# HTML5 video buffering before the playback

Tags: html5-video

I have an html page, and a link to the video in my code. Can I start buffering the video as soon as I've opened page, and show the 'play' button only when the video is completely buffered? Important, thet I should put this video dynamicly via innerHTML() when it's loaded. Before that, the video tag shouldn't be on the page at all.

Comment: You might be able to hack something that would work on some browsers, but I don't think the solution would scale to all HTML5 players - such as on iOS where the preload attribute is ignored and the play() method is disregarded unless a user action fired it. Read http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#attr-media-preload for some basic info about how the preload and buffered attributes work.

Comment: No, actually everything was very simple. I tried the videojs plugin, so my task is done for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution I have used [video.js](http://videojs.com/) jquery plugin.