# Start playing HTML5 Video only after the complete video is buffered

Tags: javascript, html, video, model-view-controller

Is there a way I can start playing my HTML5 MP4 video only after the entire video is buffered (100%). When it is in the process of buffering, I should display the Loading screen. Please help. This code should work in both Firefox and IE11.

Hyperlink Titles Example :
- Play Video1: Fav Foods - Play Video1: Fav Veg - Play Video2: Fav Animal

And here is the code I have when I click on the hyperlink and also the Video tags. I load the video dynamically from the database. The attribute 'pos' tells the time in seconds where the player has to seek playing.

```
<video id="VideoContainer" controls="controls" style="width:500px;height:320px" preload="auto">
<source id="VideoData" src=@Model.IntroVideoPath type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

```
<a onclick="navVideo('@items.FileName','@items.StartSec');">@items.DisplayText</a>

 function navVideo(fileName, pos) {
    //Get Player and the source
    var player = document.getElementById('VideoContainer');
    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('VideoData');
    var mp4CurVid = $(mp4Vid).attr('src');

    //Reload the player only if the file name changes
    if (mp4CurVid != fileName) {            
        $(mp4Vid).attr('src', fileName);
        player.load();

        player.play();
        if (pos != 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                player.currentTime = pos;
                player.play();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = pos;
        player.play();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video buffering before the playback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963934/html5-video-buffering-before-the-playback)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the encoding technique for that MP4 file. I encoded with different settings (random settings options for Mp4) and finally got that to work without buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the this http://videojs.com/ to get that to work.